# Getting value from SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Database named `Server` and `DatabaseHelper`.
I'm trying to get a value from base

```
private DatabaseHelper db;
db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
int have = db.getAxe(Column_ID);
```

where in DatabaseHelper

```
public int getAxe(long id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(Server.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Server.COLUMN_ID, Server.COLUMN_AXE},
            Server.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Server.COLUMN_AXE));

}
```

but i get run time error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

If needed i can provide a `Server` code, but i think problem is somewhere here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.query` returns a NonNull cursor positioned at the index -1, you have to move it to 0, and if it doesnt move to 0 it means no data is returned.

You have to call `cursor.moveToNext()` before reading the FIRST position, call it before `cursor.getInt()`

```
if (cursor.moveToNext()) // if true it have data, otherwise a empty cursor was returned
   return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Server.COLUMN_AXE));
else
   return -1;
```

Also remember to call cursor.close() after reading everything you want from it, usually as:

```
try {
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) // if true it have data, otherwise a empty cursor was returned
       return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Server.COLUMN_AXE));
    else
       return -1;
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My db helper class may help you with exceptions.
getUser function is similar to your needs.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = DatabaseHandler.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYDB";

private static final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

private static final String TABLE_USER = "_USER";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "_USER_ID";
private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "_USER_NAME";
private static final String KEY_USER_PASSWORD = "_USER_PASSWORD";
private static final String KEY_USER_BAR = "_USER_BAR";
private static final String KEY_USER_LASTLOGIN = "_USER_LASTLOGIN";
private static final String DROP_TABLE_USER = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_USER + " ("
        + KEY_USER_ID + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_USER_BAR + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
        + KEY_USER_LASTLOGIN + " TEXT)";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

private static void beginReadLock() {
    rwLock.readLock().lock();
}

private static void endReadLock() {
    rwLock.readLock().unlock();
}

private static void beginWriteLock() {
    rwLock.writeLock().lock();
}

private static void endWriteLock() {
    rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_USER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}

public void clearAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    onCreate(db);
}

public void clearUser() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        beginWriteLock();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (db != null) {
            try {
                if (db.isOpen()) {
                    db.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
            endWriteLock();
        }
    }
}

public void setUser(SignInRequestModel user, String userId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String currentTime = dateFormat.format(now);
    try {
        beginWriteLock();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USER_ID, userId);
        values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(KEY_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_USER_BAR, user.getBarId());
        values.put(KEY_USER_LASTLOGIN, currentTime);
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (db != null) {
            try {
                if (db.isOpen()) {
                    db.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
            endWriteLock();
        }
    }
}



public SignInRequestModel getUser(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    SignInRequestModel requestModel = new SignInRequestModel();
    try {
        beginReadLock();
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_USER,
                new String[]{KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_USER_PASSWORD, KEY_USER_BAR},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                KEY_USER_LASTLOGIN + " DESC",
                "1"
        );
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                requestModel = new SignInRequestModel(
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_BAR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_NAME)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_PASSWORD))
                );
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (db != null) {
            try {
                if (db.isOpen()) {
                    db.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
            endReadLock();
        }
    }
    return requestModel;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my response at other questions

I am looping through all the record and take the last record in this case, assuming you only have 1 record returning, it will be fine with this code.
If you don't want to loop and you know it is always going to be one record you can remove the do while loop and use only the cursor.moveToFirst()

```
public int getAxe(long id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    long returnId = 0;

    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = db.query(Server.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Server.COLUMN_ID, Server.COLUMN_AXE}, Server.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);


        if (cursor.getCount() != 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                returnId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Server.COLUMN_AXE));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return returnId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an `out of bounds -1` is that the cursor is at position -1 BEFORE THE FIRST ROW. You need to MOVE to a position so that you can extract data.

The message also indicates that you have 1 row in the cursor.

You could use :-

```
public int getAxe(long id)
{
    int rv = -1; 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(Server.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Server.COLUMN_ID, Server.COLUMN_AXE},
            Server.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Server.COLUMN_AXE));
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<< should always close cursors when done with them
    return rv; 
}
```

- Notes

  - If no row is found then -1 will be returned (this may or may not suit)
  - The above code is in-principle code, it hasn't been tested and may have errors.